# How to handle Buffer coming from NextJS backend API

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, buffer

I have a NextJS application where one of the backend API routes returns a JSON object that contains a [buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

```js
// nodeConfiguration has a nodeId property which is a buffer
res.status(200).json(nodeConfiguration);
```

When I receive this response on the frontend, I try to output the `nodeId` (`data.nodeId.toString()`) but what gets displayed is `[object Object]`.

I tried to check if I am indeed getting a buffer on the frontend:

```js
console.log(data.nodeId);
```

And on the dev console, I get this:

```
nodeId: {type: 'Buffer', data: Array(8)}
```

But when I use the [`isBuffer()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferisbufferobj) to check:

```js
Buffer.isBuffer(data.nodeId) ? 'buffer' : 'not buffer';
```

I get **not buffer**. I am confused and I don't understand what's happening here. What am I doing wrong and how do I properly pass a buffer to and from the backend?

Comment: JSON does not support buffer type. You cannot send a buffer in JSON format. If you really want to serve buffered content, it will be served on a separate request that will serve only that content

Comment: @vijayant my thought was that sending it from the backend to the frontend will stringify the buffer and then converted back to buffer at the frontend. It's okay, I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

So according to [this documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer):

> The `Buffer` class is a subclass of JavaScript's `Uint8Array` class and
> extends it with methods that cover additional use cases.

I ended up reading through its documentation and apparently I could do something like:

```js
// @ts-ignore
const uint8array = new Uint8Array(node.nodeId.data);
console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(uint8array));
```

I had to add `@ts-ignore` because in the eyes of Typescript, `nodeId` is a buffer and it doesn't have a `data` property. This finally gives me the string representation of the buffer.